# JaCoCo no coverage

Tags: java, ant, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using JaCoCo [offline instrumentation](http://mcs.une.edu.au/doc/jacoco/doc/ant.html#instrument) with ANT. It instruments all the classes perfectly and when running the report task, the number of classes drops by 11. IOW, # if classes instrumented is 53 whereas the at the time of report generation, the log says 'Writing bundle 'JaCoCo Coverage Report' with 42 classes'. I have already tried the solution [Jacoco - Zero Percent Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366428/jacoco-zero-percent-coverage) and hasn't helped. I have also ensured the classes used for instrumentation and at runtime are the same.

Comment: Please share the ant file.. (as edit to original question)

Comment: Do you have same # of source (java/groovy/etc files) for the classes files? i.e. do you have 42 source files or 53? If you are generating java files on the fly (wsdl > java) then, there's possibility that jacoco doesn't know the location of your source files to get those dynamically created source files (11 files for which you have the class files but not source files in the src/main/... or src/java etc custom location)